# Can not connect to postgresql in libpq

Tags: sql, c, database, postgresql, libpq

I can't connect to database using this code:

```
void connect_to_db(){
        connection = PQconnectdb("user=username password=123 dbname=project_db");
        printf("%s\n", PQerrorMessage(connection));

}

int main() {
        connect_to_db();
        PQfinish(connection);
        return 0;
}
```

when I run the program it prints the error:
`FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "username"`.
I had created a database and username with these commands in psql shell:

```
CREATE DATABASE yourdbname;
CREATE USER youruser WITH ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'yourpass';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE yourdbname TO youruser;
```

this is  `pg_hba.conf` file:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer
# IPv4 local connections:
#host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            ident
host    all     all     127.0.0.1/32        md5
# IPv6 local connections:
#host    all             all             ::1/128                 ident
host    all     all     ::1/128         md5
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
#local   replication     all                                     peer
#host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            ident
#host    replication     all             ::1/128                 ident
```

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen where is this address in fedora?`/etc/postgresql/9.1/main/pg_hba.conf*`

Comment: need actual `pg_hba.conf` file, not sample.

Comment: pg_hba.conf.sample itself is not the real pg_hba.conf.  It is a template used by initdb to create the real one.

Comment: 'locate' takes some time for it's index to pick up new files. 
Did you just init the database recently? Can you find postgresql.conf?  It should be in the same directory as that, but it might also be given an alternate name or location.

Comment: @jjanes thanks! now it's content of `pg_hba.conf`. would you help me find the problem?

Comment: Change 'peer' to 'md5' and restart the database.